# Finding bounds to apply Dominated Convergence

Tags: measure-theory

i was filling some gaps on a proof my teacher made in class, to compute
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
The first he made was saying that this integral is equal to
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_0^\infty \frac{\varepsilon \sin x}{e^{\varepsilon x}-1} \, \mathrm{d}x,$$
and he said "okay, you can check that at home". I tried to apply Dominated Convergence Theorem in
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}-\frac{\varepsilon \sin x}{e^{\varepsilon x}-1} \, \mathrm{d}x,$$
and show that it's zero, because I already know that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not Lebesgue-integrable. So, I tried to bound the function inside the integral sign, but I'm not getting very sharp bounds (essentialy, I tried to apply MVT a couple times and get
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}\xi e^{-\tau},$$
with $0<\tau<\xi<\varepsilon x$, but then I take absolute value and get something like $\varepsilon$). Do you have any idea/hint to bound this with an integrable function?

**Edit**: As Delta-u pointed out, my approach can't work. Do you have any idea to prove the equality?

Comment: The problem with $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ not being in $L^1$ is that for any $g \in L^1$, $f-g \not \in L^1$, so $\frac{\sin x}{x}-\frac{\varepsilon \sin x}{e^{\varepsilon x}-1}$ is not Lebesgue-integrable.

Comment: Of course! if $g \in L^1$ and $f-g \in L^1$ we'll get $f=(f-g)+g \in L^1$, right? So, i'm screw :s